# how to set specific size to embed videos in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, video

I put embed codes of videos in custom field, every embed code (video) from every site have a different size..
there is a way to set a specific size for all embed videos without change the sizes in the embed codes?
i mean just copy and past the embed code with all parameters and then some code will change the videos to specific size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with CSS or JS. For example, you can:

- Have specific width and height for iframe in css
- Have a JS script that will resize your iframe dynamically, for example on document.ready.

An example of the CSS would be something like:

`.content iframe { width: 600px; height: 480px; }`

An example of the JS would be something like:

```
jQuery(function($) {

    var iframes = $('.content iframe');
    iframes.css('width', 600);
    iframes.css('height', 480);

});
```

Please, note that these examples would apply to iframes that are within an element with class "content", for example `<div class="content">`.